# Android Support Library - Preview?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-print-framework

Is it possible to find out what functionality will be included in forthcoming Android support libraries?

I ask as I need to add a printing feature to my app - but my `minSdkVersion` is `15` and the printing api in Android was only introduced in API 19. So I would like to know if printing may be added to the support library later (hopefully in the near future) or whether I should start trying to find some decent third party printing libraries.

If it isn't possible to know beforehand what features will be in future support libraries, is it normal for Android features to be added ***later*** to the support library, or are they generally added to the support library at the same time they are added to the main Android library?

Comment: Usually later, but I would go for 3rd party solution because waiting for anything (features or bugfixes) in support may take ages (at least a year). On the other hand if something that old didn't appear yet I wouldn't say it will appear ever.